# Adding a list of dataframes to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to add a list of 7 dataframes to a dictionary, where the key is the dataframe name and the value is the dataframe itself, like so:

```
    {"Clock 1": clock1_df, "Clock 2": clock2_df, ...}
```

I've created a list with the dataframe names, and then try to put the two lists into a dictionary, but it only adds the last element of each list to the dict:

```
    adict = dict(zip(f_names_list, dataframes))
```

or

```
    bdict = {k:v for k, v in zip(f_names_list, dataframes)}
```

Q: Why is only the last element of each list in the dict?
Am I mad for trying to add a list of dataframes to a dictionary? 
Both lists have unique values.

I make the dataframes list like so:

```
path = 'dat/'
f = []

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
    f.extend(filenames)
    break

dataframes = []
for filename in filenames:
  dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(path+filename, sep=" ", header = None))
  for df in dataframes:
    df.name = filename[:-10]
    df.columns = ['Time', 'Measurement']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
for df in dataframes:
    df.name = filename[:-10]
    df.columns = ['Time', 'Measurement']
```

This is inside the first for so you are modifying all data frames, by the end, all data frames will have the same name data, keep in mind that when you defined `df` this variable contains the reference to the item in the list, so you everything in the list is modified.

I don't know how the data looks like but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
dataframes = []
for filename in filenames:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(path+filename, sep=" ", header = None))
    df = dataframes[-1]
    df.name = filename[:-10]
    df.columns = ['Time', 'Measurement']
```

Both methods with zip, are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
d = {}
for filename in filenames:
    d[filename] = pd.read_csv(path+filename, sep=" ", header = None)
```

Here, the key will have the name of dataframe(i.e., filename) and the value is the actual dataframe.

You can read from dict like this:

```
for key, val in d.items():
    print(key,val)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Really like the way you create the dictionary, looks more efficient/much better than what I do.